# What are the quantum algorithms available for Monte Carlo sampling?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, resource-request, variational-quantum-algorithms

What are the quantum algorithms available for performing Monte Carlo sampling. Is there any implementation of these algorithms. Any kind of resources would be helpful